# Are testng listeners thread safe for file operation

Tags: selenium, testng

Are testng listeners thread safe? Suppose i am using iTestListener and need to update a text file based on the test failure/pass. I am planning to use onTestFailure() and onTestPass() of the testng listener. These methods will call another method, which will be having the logic to update the text file. So should i use synchronized keyword / synchronized block in this new method?

Thanks
Mathew

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer...

Testng listeners are not thread safe.